# Remove partial similar values in array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have a variable `$data` below:

```
$data = array(
    [90]=> array(
        [0] => array(
            [userID] => 90
            [dateLogin] =>  23:35:13
            [type] => 28
         ),
        [1]=>array(
            [userID] => 90
            [dateLogin] =>  23:35:10
            [type] => 29
        )
      ),
    [91]=> array(
        [0]=>array(
            [userID] => 91
            [dateLogin] =>  23:35:13
            [type] => 25
         ).
        [1]=>array(
            [userID] => 91
            [dateLogin] =>  23:35:10
            [type] => 23
         )
      ), 
   )
```

What I want is to remove the array with same time dateLogin and leave only 1 array where the dateLogin seconds is the smallest. The output I want to achieve is:

```
$data = array(
    [90]=> array(
        [0]=>array(
            [userID] => 90
            [dateLogin] =>  23:35:10
            [type] => 29
         ),
     ), 
    [91]=> array(
        [0]=>array(
            [userID] => 91
            [dateLogin] =>  23:35:10
            [type] => 23
        )
     ), 
   )
```

I tried this code but not work:

```
  foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
       foreach ($value as $k => $v) {
           $temp = $v['dateLogin'];
              if($temp> $v['dateLogin']){
                 unset($data_list[$key]);
               }
        }
   }
```

Any help thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just keep index 0 if others are duplicate Try

```
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
   $temp[$key] = $value[0];
}
print_r($temp);
```

Comment: Should be $value[1]

Comment: @MeganFox any reason?

Comment: $value[1] contains the smallest time but though i up-voted for the good answer

Comment: @MeganFox Thanks, this is just logic, if OP wants to get any other index he can

Comment: He mentioned that in the question , so i was a bit specific